# Ember.js in windows (8) store app requires MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction

Tags: windows-8, ember.js, windows-store-apps

We are currently evaluating ember.js for use inside a **javascript windows (8) store application**. 
The application itself is not much of interrest itself. The problems we are facing are related 
to the restrictions that apply when working with dynamic content being injected into the DOM. 
The Windows store app runs in "local" context, i.e. the way how windows store applications are 
typically built. In the local context, the html "browser host" of the windows store application
works in a rather restricted mode. For instance setting innerHTML, outerHTML or appending content
holding script elements will all get blocked if not explicitely encapuslated by a "proxy" function
provide by Microsoft (**MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction**).

Example: Ember.View appendTo will not work out of the box. In order to get it work, the function has to encapsulate the jQuery call to appendTo with the  MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction proxy function.

ORIGINAL: (in Ember.View)

```
appendTo: function(target) {
    // Schedule the DOM element to be created and appended to the given
    // element after bindings have synchronized.
    this._insertElementLater(function() {
        Ember.assert("You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.", !Ember.$(target).is('.ember-view') && !Ember.$(target).parents().is    ('.ember-view'));
        this.$().appendTo(target);          
    });
    return this;
  },
```

**MODIFIED** to work with Windows Store App

```
appendTo: function(target) {
    // Schedule the DOM element to be created and appended to the given
    // element after bindings have synchronized.
    this._insertElementLater(function() {
        Ember.assert("You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.", !Ember.$(target).is('.ember-view') && !Ember.$(target).parents().is    ('.ember-view'));
        var self = this;
        MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
            self.$().appendTo(target);
        });
    });
    return this;
  },
```

Are there any plans to support windows store apps or is there any advice of how to solve this problem without patching ember code all over? I was really searching a lot, but it seems that there are not many people trying to get ember.js working inside a javascript windows store application. I'd really would like to use it as our "core" JavaScript framework for building hybrid/cross plattform javaScript applications.

Libraries I used

- ember-1.0.0-rc.3
- handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3
- jquery-2.0.0 (suppose to be ready for Windows 8 apps)
- jquery-ui-1.10.3

Microsoft explains the limitations mentioned above [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465388.aspx):

Thank's a lot for any response and ideas... any help would be appreciated!

**Note:** posted to ember disucssion forum: [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-js-in-windows-8-store-app-requires-msapp-execunsafelocalfunction/1240)

Comment: I don't think there is a way around that in the current state of both Ember.js the Win8 Store Apps platform. You will likely have to customize Ember to work specifically for that platform; though I would probably try to contact a contributor if I were you.

Comment: Your right, that's what I probably have to do. Thanks for answering. If I get any news, I'll post it here.

Comment: @AleB, Did you got any news? Or did you find any way around this?